# Ad Hoc distribution Xcode 10, App not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10, ad-hoc-distribution

I have created Ad-Hoc distribution certificates for my app
But when i install through xcode 10 my app stuck at the splash screen even restarting app is not working.

But i upload app in https://diawi.com it works perfectly 
I don't understand why it's not working directly with xcode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this gif. It works for me.

[image: please check this gif]

Comment: It worked but that should be automatic. Every time developer will have ton edit the scheme when he/she switches to Debug and Release Mode. Is there any way to achieve that by itself?

Comment: its takes a lot of time and xcode stucks on Indexing and Pre-building. Seems like it is take same as creating a new archive and generating IPA.